# Do any STL implementations support C++ concepts?

Tags: c++, stl, libstdc++, c++-concepts

I am working on a class project which uses C++ concepts. Where can I find an STL implementation that supports has constraints from the [concepts draft TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf), such as `Equality_comparable` or `Sortable`?

Thanks for your help!

---

Here's what I tried so far:

I've successfully compiled the [`c++-concepts` branch from GCC's SVN](https://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/c++-concepts/), which appears to be maintained (last updated yesterday by Andrew Sutton). However, the libstdc++ that comes with this branch has not been updated for concepts.

I also tried [Concepts-Lite](http://concepts.axiomatics.org/%7Eans/) (gcc-clite), which promises:

> The standard library shipping with this compiler includes the constraints found in the paper ["A Concept Design for the STL"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf), which can be accessed by including the `<type_traits>` header file.

However, libstdc++ in the GCC code downloaded from that page also does not have concepts. In particular, the `type_traits` header appears to be unchanged from the GCC revision it was forked from.

Comment: I doubt you can find it anywhere

Comment: That draft TS doesn't specify *anything* in the library; it's purely a language extension.

Comment: Right, it is not in release gcc. But the clite page quoted implies that they implemented concepts on their fork of libstdc++, 2 years ago! :-)

Comment: `gcc-clite-0.2.tar.bz2` does seem to have some concepts stuff in its library. You might want to send an email to Andrew Sutton.

Comment: STL != "C++ Standard Library".  Which is your question about?  Just the containers?  Or the whole library?

Comment: @KevinChen I think the only part of concepts in libstdc++ back then is the really primitive stuff like __is_class, __is_base_of, etc.  i.e. the front end helpers used also for <type_traits>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Andrew Sutton's Origin library on github](https://github.com/asutton/origin).  If you follow the `origin/core` directory you can find the basic concepts.  He has some graph, math, and some container stuff stuff too from the look of it.

I have to admit that I'm in the middle of exploring this myself so I have no intelligent report yet.

Only downside: the most recent check-ins are a couple of months or more ago.  I guess we'll see.

Comment: In parallel to this question, I emailed Andrew and that's what he said to use. Thanks!

Comment: I was wrong about the activity in the Origin library.  As of 3/30/2015 the check-in to the core library is only 5 days old.  Cool beans.

Comment: A note from future: the suggested library ***differs*** from the currently accepted standard concepts specification (http://eel.is/c++draft/concepts), its concept implementations are not equivalent to standard ones.

Comment: Two up to date implementations: https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2.git